# He was studying or he studied?

Tags: grammar, verbs, british-english, past-tense

Is it correct to say "Jimmy learned how to rock climb when he was studying at Carleton College" or is it better to say "Jimmy learned how to rock climb when he studied at Carleton College"?

Comment: The first one is more  natural. He was a student for a period of time, during which other things happened to him. The second almost implies that rock-climbing was part of his college course, which is presumably not what you mean.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a hyphenated 'rock-climb'? "Jimmy learned how to rock climb when he was studying at Carleton College" doesn't clearly say that both actions were of the same duration, whereas the second example says that.

Answer (score -1):

If you are simply *implying the fact* that Jimmy learned rock climbing while studying then the use of past continuous tense in the first sentence is more appropriate. It also can be said that:

> Jimmy **was learning** how to rock climb when he **was studying** at Carleton
>   College